# Difference Between the two lines

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class named Ellipse
Then , what is the difference between the two lines

```
1-Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
2-Ellipse e;
```

I know by first , I can access all the elements of ellipse class as it is creating the object of Ellipse class . But with second , I can do the same

What is the difference between the two. What can I do from first line and not by second or viceversa

Comment: Attempting to call any methods on `e` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks , That make sense

Answer (score 1):

Line 1 & 2: you declare Ellipse variables, first a variable called `ellipse` variable and second, one called `e`.

- Line 1: you assign a viable object or reference to the ellipse variable. You can now call Ellipse methods on the variable and access any public fields.
- Line 2: you don't assign anything to the `e` variable and instead it has nothing but a null reference, and you can't do anything with it yet. If you try to use the variable *before* assigning the reference, you risk getting a NullPointerException.

Think of a variable like an empty cup. You have two cups, and the first one, ellipse, you have filled with beer and can drink from it and be satisfied. The second one, `e` is empty, and if you try to drink from it, you'll be sorely disappointed.

Comment: Thanks , That make sense

Answer (score 0):

Java is not C++, `Ellipse e;` does not allocate a `new Ellipse()`, it's equivalent to `Ellipse e = null;` In contract the first example constructs an `Ellipse` instance and assigns the reference to the variable `ellipse`.

Answer (score 0):

Line 1 - Declared and initialize a new Ellipse object and assigned it to a variable ellipse.

Line 2, Declared a variable e of type Ellipse.